# Periscope style mirrors for road bike

Tags: road-bike, mirrors, april-fools

I just got this bike, and put it in the classic "aggressive position".  I also ran out and bought spandex.[image: apparently, this is cool]
I was just wondering if there are periscope style mirrors I can fasten to the down tube so that I can actually see forward while I am trapeezing?

Comment: Mirror or no, I'd recommend that you accelerate *very* slowly.

Comment: I'm looking for a seatpost about that long to use on my folder.  Can I get one somewhere other than photoshop ?

Comment: I suggest a slight forward tilt of the seat for a more natural fit. I'd also relocate the water bottle holder onto the seat tube, perhaps.

Comment: BTW you forgot to edit the shadow.

Comment: Those are not bottle holders, they are claws to hold pokeballs.

Comment: This question is not clear. Should the periscopes go up, down, or forward?

Comment: Your mention of the periscope gives me an idea. We could use some sort of device that would allow a bicyclist to peer downward, while actually seeing forward (without the view being left-right reversed).  The vantage point would be close to the ground, giving a heightened sense of speed. (Which is half the point of these aggressive postures: simply having your head down thanks to drop handle bars, you *feel* faster, the same way you feel faster in a go-cart doing 50 than in an 18 wheeler rig's cabin doing 80).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bike humour is off topic for this stack.

Comment: Can we vote somewhere to make bike humour *on* topic? After all there is a *funny* tag already, how to put that to good use when humour isn't allowed?

Comment: @stijn meta.bicycles might work, or you could go there and suggest something. Perhaps a community wiki of bicycle humor? The funny tag is a new invention by this poster, so saying "the person created a new tag for this post, therefore the post is acceptable"... it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I suppose some folks will insist on closing it, but please don't delete it.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I think moving it to meta.bicycles SE would be more appropriate either that or it really just belongs in a chat forums.

Comment: @stijn  I only added the funny tag for this post.   Closure means "there won't be a good answer coming" vs delete which removes the question completely.

Comment: @Rider_X - No one ever looks at meta.

Comment: @DanielRHicks and rather than suffer a flood of either spam or silly photoshop jobs, I think we should stop this now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because April Fools is over.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the tilt of the seat tube, this setup does not make for efficient pedaling. The seat is sitting over the center of the rear wheel, which moves your entire center of gravity too far to the back. You want the center of gravity to be a bit ahead of the bottom bracket, where the downward force is applied to the pedals. That's one of the two main reasons for the aggressive position: that forward center of gravity. The other reason is aerodynamics, of course.  I suggest creating a zig-zagged seat tube:

[image]

This is just to convey the basic idea. Any good pro shop can make the required ground shadow adjustment that must accompany this modification, and other necessary details.

**Huge bonus:** This seat post is guaranteed to absorb road vibrations better than even the nimblest vintage 1970's Italian road bike frames.

Comment: What a pleasure it is to read this!!! Finally, someone with a sense of humour on this site!  All the best. I'm curious how many 'angry' answers I will get.

Comment: @msladtmn Ironically, you will be closed as "not constructive", in spite of the impressively built-up seat post.

Comment: okay, but it was funny!

Comment: @msladtmn it would be funny if you actually built it. As it is it's just "photoshop humor" - it looks like humor, but it's not real. People have built real bikes that are really funny. You haven't.

Comment: I think it was funnier than that stupid Z-shaped crank.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Oh my, it took me a few seconds to remember. Yes, that product claiming to have mechanical advantages that anyone with a grade 11 physics background can see aren't real.

Answer (score 2):

There was [an attempt](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1457425032) to kickstart a bike periscope last year. Unfortunately, Pedi-Scope has failed to reach funding goal, but person behind [promised](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1457425032/pedi-scope-the-periscope-for-your-bicycle/posts/1227407) to "get in touch if he plans to relaunch the project", so link might become helpful again some day.

[image: pedisope]

Comment: Haha, this is exactly what I thought when I saw the subject. My vote for closing reason is either shopping recommendation or guerrilla advertising for that guy's next kickstarter.

Comment: Great spotting.  Terrible idea but you have some serious google-fu.

Answer (score 0):

Race Across American ... about 30 years ago
I saw a rider using one of these (home made).
(I saw it on the commercial TV coverage of RAAM)
For anyone that has spent 20 hours during a day riding a
gravel road across the hills of North Dakota while covering 189 miles ...
This would be a welcome addition.
Many also scoff at having a rear view mirror.
Same difference.   Rear view has saved my life
on at least 5 occasions.

Watch any bicyclist on a road cycle.  Note how often they
ride for short intervals with head down ... looking up
to check road.

Then there was the time an oncoming motorist launched his
drink cup at my head.  Oncoming ice filled cup at 40+ mph
while riding on 2' raised sidewalk across causeway.

Head tucked to let my helmet shield me.
Would have been a good time for this device.

I tried a reverse mirror (rather than a prism) years ago.
makes the brain do extra processing.

Also, as I age and muscles vanish ... even more desireable.

50 years cycling ...
hit by car once (survived because of mirror providing me warning)
fell once on RR track
Fell once at 1mph on a hill climb on sand road (chain came off)
Fell once (endo coming off steep down slope parking lot
had to hit brake to avoid car)
Fell once at age 12 with a passenger on the seat and me proving engine.
---- And I road OVER a 4'x4' A frame road hazard sign when I was
looking down and hammering on pedals.  (no fall)
.... and I suppose a few skinned body parts when I started at age three.
Not a bad safety record ... although I am perhaps overly cautious
... but I live on.
I still expect to die like the raccoons and skunks I pass every ride.

Ahh.  Life is joy.   Totally worth it.
Every now and again I feel the joy I felt when I lost the training wheels.

--- Climbers use something similar == 'belay glasses' to avoid 'belay neck'
EXACTLY the same muscle pain.  Except cyclists do it MORE.

As to the view:  Better than the view from a car rear view mirror.
Few think they are silly ... a mirror just to keep you from having
to turn your head and look.